# Practical statistics for queueing networks

Tags: st.statistics, queueing-theory, discrete-dynamical-systems

There is a theory for queueing networks where we postulate some nicely behaving base distributions of arrival processes and service processes and then calculate the behaviour of the system.

Now, in reality, distributions are hardly ideal.

What should I read to get an introduction on

- how to measure arrival and service processes' distribution
- how to create a model of the system
- how to draw conclusions on how to improve the throughput of the system, based on the measurements and modelling?